# Speed up insert table in database using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using python for coding and psql for save my data.
My problem is that when I write into database it takes about 2-3 minutes.
Size of the data is about 1,200,000 (lines) and 3 columns.

Insertion function:

```
def store_data(cur,table_name,data):
    cur.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO"+" "+table_name+" "+"(name, date,id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
    [(data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2]) for i in xrange(0,len(data))]
    )

    cur.connection.commit()
```

How to speed-up function?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `COPY` command. [Postgres Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html). Also check out the psycopg [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) on COPY.

Some numbers: Separate INSERT for 3 million rows: 3 hours. Using COPY: 7 seconds.

Comment: It's more faster?

Comment: Added some numbers. They originate from the Database Tuning class that I tought.

Comment: I save my data into array list.

Comment: Convert it to some CSV format that COPY likes, e.g. using StringIO (python 2) or io.StringIO (python 3)

Answer (score 1):

There is a detailed chapter in the **excellent** PostgreSQL Docs about ["Populating a Database"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/populate.html)

In addition to use [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html) as W.Mann suggests you can do more if you have further performance requirements:

- Remove Indexes temporary
- Remove Foreign Key and Check Constraints temporary
- Increase maintenance_work_mem
- Increase max_wal_size
- Disable WAL Archival and Streaming Replication
- Run ANALYZE Afterwards

If you use pg_restore you can try to use the `-j` option on a multi processor system to run multiple jobs parallel. And check out the other options given in the documentation linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of [executemany](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html):

```
Warning
In its current implementation this method is not faster than 
executing execute() in a loop. For better performance you can use 
the functions described in Fast execution helpers.
```

At the same location a link can be found to: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-exec they recommend:

```
 psycopg2.extras.execute_batch
```